# How to put variables as input when running GPT command

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I would like to process multiple images in Python with a for loop.

When I try to do it for one file it works, for example:

```
!gpt "Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml" -t "result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip/s1_cal_deb/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip_Cal_deb_script.dim" "./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"
```

However I want to do it for many files, so I tested this in Python 3.

```
deb = (f'"{"Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml"}"') 
deb = deb + " -t "

url = (f'"{"result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"}')
url5 = (f'{"S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"}')       
url2 = (f'{"/s1_cal_deb/"}')
url3 = (f'{url5}')
url4 = (f'{"_Cal_deb_script.dim"}"')
source = (f'"{"./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"}"')

output = url + url2 + url3 + url4

final = deb + output + " " + source

final
```

Output:

```
'"Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml" -t "result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip/s1_cal_deb/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip_Cal_deb_script.dim" "./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"'
```

The final string is exactly the same as the first one. But I get the following error:

```
INFO: org.esa.snap.core.gpf.operators.tooladapter.ToolAdapterIO: Initializing external tool adapters
INFO: org.esa.snap.core.util.EngineVersionCheckActivator: Please check regularly for new updates for the best SNAP experience.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operator SPI not found for operator [final]
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.annotations.ParameterDescriptorFactory.getOpSpi(ParameterDescriptorFactory.java:262)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.annotations.ParameterDescriptorFactory.createMapBackedOperatorPropertyContainer(ParameterDescriptorFactory.java:67)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.CommandLineTool.convertParameterMap(CommandLineTool.java:400)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.CommandLineTool.runOperator(CommandLineTool.java:296)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.CommandLineTool.runGraphOrOperator(CommandLineTool.java:284)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.CommandLineTool.run(CommandLineTool.java:188)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.CommandLineTool.run(CommandLineTool.java:121)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.GPT.run(GPT.java:54)
    at org.esa.snap.core.gpf.main.GPT.main(GPT.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.esa.snap.runtime.Launcher.lambda$run$0(Launcher.java:55)
    at org.esa.snap.runtime.Engine.runClientCode(Engine.java:189)
    at org.esa.snap.runtime.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.esa.snap.runtime.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:65)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:101)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:26)

Error: Operator SPI not found for operator [final]
```

I'm a missing something very obvious here? I am new to F strings in Python so I would really appreciate any help.

Some Examples:

```
deb = (f'"{"Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml"}"') # This is the script to run
    deb = deb + " -t " 

url = (f'"{"result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"}') # output folder
url5 = (f'{"S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"}')  # input file      
url2 = (f'{"/s1_cal_deb/"}') # output folder
url3 = (f'{url5}') # filename
url4 = (f'{"_Cal_deb_script.dim"}"') # output file extention
source = (f'"{"./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"}"') # input file 

output = url + url2 + url3 + url4

final = deb + output + " " + source

final
```

This creates the following string:

Output:

```
'"Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml" -t "result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip/s1_cal_deb/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip_Cal_deb_script.dim" "./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"'
```

But I want the following string:

```
 "Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml" -t "result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip/s1_cal_deb/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip_Cal_deb_script.dim" "./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"
```

I want to convert:

> '"Method/gpt... to "Method/gpt... on both ends of the string

Then I could run the !gpt command as following:

```
!gpt final
```

I hope this is clearer.

Many Thanks,

Ishack

Comment: You are doing something wrong with your f-strings. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hi Jack, instead of manually writing the gpt command like the first one, which works. I am trying to create them by using variables and then joining them. This is because i want to apply the same gpt command to multiple files e.g with a for loop.

Comment: Can you post a couple of examples of the variables and then the way you expect them to look after you join them? I may be missing something, but I can't figure it out from the way your question is phrased.

Comment: Hi Jack, I have commented the code with a example and also showed the desired output. Could you take a look please?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find a solution in Python.

```
#example command

command = 'cmd /k "gpt Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml -t ../s1_pc/s1/deb/unit/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190224T003144_20190224T003211_026064_02E80B_0ECE_cal_deb.dim ../s1_pc/s1/s1_slc/unit1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190224T003144_20190224T003211_026064_02E80B_0ECE.zip"'

os.system(command) # Start GPT command in the Jupyter Notebook cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer because, as you'll see below, the issue is probably with gpt (which I'm not that familiar with). But in trying to figure it out, I found a few things that may be helpful to you anyway.
First and foremost, your code is unnecessarily complex and the f-string don't do (in this case) anything, just clutter the code. I would rewrite it like this:

```
deb = '"Method/gpt_scripts/s1_cal_deb.xml"' + " -t " 
url = "result_step1/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"
url2 = "/s1_cal_deb/"
url3 = "S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"
url4 = "_Cal_deb_script.dim" 

source = "./Rader Images/S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20190928T003154_20190928T003221_029214_035175_65FA.zip"
output = '"'+url+url2+url3+url4+'"'
final = deb + output + " " + '"'+source+'"'
```

This gets you to the same `final` as in the question. 
As to the problem with the string: this is how python works:

```
hi = 'hi there!'
print(hi) #using the print method
hi #without using the print method
```

Output:

```
hi there!   
'hi there!'
```

You notice the difference? The single quotes aren't really part of the string, just part of the screen output when you don't issue a print command. This is why I said this isn't a complete answer: I don't know how to force gpt to accept the string itself as the argument. You may want to post that particular issue (with the simplified 'hi' example) as a seprate question. It's possible (likely) someone smarter than me can figure it out.

Sorry about that last part; hope this was useful to you anyway....

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks for clearing up my code. I will change the question and see if anyone will respond. Like you said, the hardest bit to force gpt to accept those variables as inputs. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Hi Jack, do you know how to pass that command to the command line interface in Python? I found that gpt works best in command prompt

Comment: @IshackMarshook - I'm not sure I understand; what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Jack, please see the following post to understand what I mean https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325570/sar-processing-using-python thanks

Comment: The above link is exactly what i am trying to do but i need help writing the code please

Comment: @IshackMarshook - I'm sorry, but it seems that part is out of my league....

Comment: No problem, Jack. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Jack, I finally managed to run cmd on Python. Thanks for showing how to make a string

Comment: @IshackMarshook - Good to hear! For the benefit of future people with the same question, maybe you should post the solution as an answer; I'll be glad to upvote it :D

Comment: Hi Jack, I have posted the solution, I hope this helps you if you ever need to run a cmd command from Python :)